# Devolver valor Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una aplicación que debe devolverle un valor al método que la invoque, he estado investigando pero la mayoría de ejemplos son de aplicaciones consola y la mía es de Forms.

He intentado de la siguiente forma:

Program.cs

```
 [STAThread]
    static string Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Formulario());

        response = Formulario.resp;

        return response;
    }
```

y en Formulario.cs:

```
internal static string resp;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   resp = "valor devuelto";
}
```

Inclusive intenté:

```
protected string Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   return resp = "valor devuelto";
}
```

Pero al intentar ejecutarlo me marca:

```
"El programa no contiene ningún método Main estático adecuado para un punto de entrada"
```

Alguna idea de cómo podría mandar el valor al método que invoque mi aplicación??
Gracias

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor lo que piensas hacer con la respuesta  que te devuelve un Form o como piensas llamarlo desde otro Form o en la clase principal Program.

Comment: Sólo quiero saber cómo mandarle una respuesta al método que invoque a mi aplicación

Comment: Es que no funciona asi.. el main, no espera que el primer formulario que llama, devuelva nada.. si queres devolver un valor de un formulario, deberias tener una propiedad publica en el, y despues de que se apague (no que se cierre, pq si se cerro perdiste todo), deberias leer esa propiedad...

Comment: mejor explica para que queres lograr esto, y vemos que te conviene...

Comment: Repito, una aplicación externa manda a llamar a mi aplicación, mi aplicación después de ejecutarse debe devolverle un resultado a la que lo invocó

Comment: Ya lo probé si se puede hacer de la forma que los buscas. Aunque no entiendo aun porque deseas hacer ya que si lo haces es procesar datos no seria mejor un clase que se dedique a eso.

Comment: Y no te marcó error como a mi????

Answer (score 0):

Yo he tenido la misma duda, y al principio lo hice como sugirió Bercklyn, pero mis colegas me recomendaron no trabajar con propiedades públicas de esa manera, sino declarándolas privadas, pero con método de propiedad público para acceder a su valor. El resultado es muy similar a lo que ya se ha visto en esta pregunta y respuesta, pero te sirve de alternativa, un poquito más segura, en el caso, por ejemplo, que no quieras que esta propiedad sea modificada desde fuera del formulario, etc.

Esto aplicado en tu código, sería algo como:

Program.cs

```
 [STAThread]
    static string Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Formulario());

        response = Formulario.Valor;

        MessageBox.Show(response);
    }
```

Formulario.cs:

```
private string resp;
public string Valor { get { return resp; } }

// Puedes asignarle el valor incluso ya en el constructor
// O puedes asignarlo en cualquier otra parte del Form
public Formulario()
{
   resp = "valor devuelto";
}
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   resp = "valor devuelto";
}
```

Comment: Ok, pero ahora desde el Main como mando el resultado???

Comment: Se supone que en Main ya recuperaste el valor al hacer `response = Formulario.Valor;` , ya tienes el valor recuperado en `response`. Eso fue lo que preguntaste. ¿Ahora necesitas usar ese valor en otro lado? ¿Dónde? No se entiende lo que necesitas.

Comment: @quinqui Creo que lo que busca es que el mismo `Main`que ejecuta el Form  devuelva la respuesta a otra aplicación.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza Pues entramos al terreno de la especulación otra vez -_- Creo que debería modificar su pregunta entonces, para aclarar bien su objetivo :o